# Trying to use css to put a Footer on page 1 only

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/therbq0h/

this link provides something similar to is being displays, its not formatted but it gives 2 pages. Has to be printed in IE.

I have a page that stores data in a database and a separate page that displays its in a generic way. I am creating custom pages to **exactly** match word documents, the way all the documents were created before. The page has a header, body, footer.

I need print to look like:
Page 1
------------Header-------------
------------Body---------------
Partial Data pulled from database entered in a form
------------footer-------------

Page 2
------------Body---------------
Partial Data pulled from database entered in a form

Page 3
------------Body---------------
remaining Data pulled from database entered in a form

data is dynamic in size.

Currently thead and tbody works fine, but i need footer on page 1 only with a horizontal line at the top.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper_class" >
        <div>
            <table style="width:100%;font-size:8pt;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:33%;">
                            Customer names:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:33%;">
                            <img src="" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:33%;">
                            Customer names:
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        some more rows and columns
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="floatCenterParent">
                                <p><%SELECT MemoField FROM Table WHERE ID = 100%></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p><%SELECT MemoField FROM Table WHERE ID = 101%></p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="some more styling">
                                more text
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            static text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="floating_Menu">
            buttons that dont get printed
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

page layout matches the word document, I need the footer on page 1 only, and must be at the bottom even if there isn't a full page. Only needs to print correctly in IE10+. If possible cross-browser would be nice.

The footer does display correctly on *every page* at the bottom except for the last page, it follows right after the body text.

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer { display: none; }
.page-one > .footer { display: block; }
```

Comment: I added the css but where to put the class and not sure what the .page-one > .footer is doing. Thanks.

Comment: The class goes on the element like so `<div class="footer">` and `.page-one > .footer' means to only target the `.footer` class that is a direct child of `.page-one`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing what I want. The .page-one seems to be a class  that i place on an outer div where the div is designed to be 1 page in length and then put a footer on that page but since I have no control over the size of each <tr>, I don't have a way of breaking the <tr> to place half the data in .page-one and the rest in pages 2+

Comment: @BrandonJacobs - Can you give me a live link? I may be able to be of more help if I can tinker.

Comment: I temporarily did some server side code to get it up in time for release, however i have to constantly change it and now have more time to revisit this. I can not give a link as it is a EMR site, however i made a quick example that if it works should be able to be adapted to my needs. The data is not fixed size so cant split it into 2 divs as that is my current method. But I will add some code to be able to test on.